# How to get the nearest value to a request param in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (`shop_staff_relationvm`) that saves the relation between a staff and a shop.

It has 3 columns: `id_shop`, `id_staff` and `change_date`.

- `id_staff` => staff foreign key
- `id_shop` => shop foreign key
- `change_date` ==> whenever a new staff-shop relation is created I save the setting date (a staff's shop may change multiple times)

The 3 abov columns represent an embeddable primary key for `shop_staff_relationvm` table.

In the query, I have 2 request params: idShop and a date.

I am trying to get the list of staffs that belong to a specific shop (`idShop`) in a specific month (`requestMonth`).

So I need to get the list of staffs when the `requestMonth` is between the first date of the relation between the staff and shop and the last date of the relation.

This is an example:

```
STAFF     | SHOP     | CHANGE DATE
----------+----------+-------------
Staff A   | Shop 1   | 10-01-2019
Staff A   | Shop 2   | 10-03-2019
Staff A   | Shop 3   | 10-05-2019
```

Assuming we have `requestMonth = 02-2019`

Then : shop 1 will have Staff A , shop 2 will have no staffs and shop 3 will have no staffs

Assuming we have `requestMonth = 03-2019`

Then : shop 1 will have no staffs , shop 2 will have Staff A and shop 3 will have no staffs

Assuming we have `requestMonth = 06-2019`

Then : shop 1 will have no staffs , shop 2 will have no staffs and shop 3 will have Staff A

This is the formula I came up with:

```
first date of relation <= requestMonth <= first date of next relation
```

I do not have a problem getting the first date of the relation, but I have a problem in getting the first date of the next relation (which I concluded to be the next nearest value to the first date of the relation).

PS: I am using JPA native query

I have tried using an `order by (change_date - first date of relation)` to get the first nearest value to the first date of relation. but It always got me the maximum value (In the example I stated above, it always gets me the `05-2019` month)

I also tried using `LEAD` to get the next nearest value. However, using the example above:

> For `requestMonth = 02-2019` :
>   the LEAD was equal to 03-2019 => correct
>
> For `requestMonth = 03-2019` :
>   the LEAD was equal to 01-2019 => wrong => It should be `05-2019`

This the whole query:

```
SELECT s.* FROM staffvm s INNER JOIN shop_staff_relationvm ss ON ss.id_staff = s.id_staff WHERE ss.id_shop = 2 and 
(CASE WHEN ((SELECT MAX(to_date(to_char(ss.change_date, 'yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM')) FROM shop_staff_relationvm ss WHERE ss.id_staff = s.id_staff) > to_date('2019-02-16', 'yyyy-MM') 
and (SELECT MIN(to_date(to_char(ss.change_date, 'yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM')) FROM shop_staff_relationvm ss WHERE ss.id_staff = s.id_staff) <= to_date('2019-02-16', 'yyyy-MM') ) 
THEN 
((SELECT ((LEAD (to_date(to_char(ss.change_date, 'yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM')) OVER (ORDER BY ss.id_staff DESC)) > to_date('2019-02-16', 'yyyy-MM') ) 
FROM shop_staff_relationvm ss WHERE ss.id_staff = s.id_staff and ss.id_shop !=2 LIMIT 1)
and 
(SELECT (MIN(to_date(to_char(ss.change_date, 'yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM')) <= to_date('2019-02-16', 'yyyy-MM'))
FROM shop_staff_relationvm ss WHERE ss.id_staff = s.id_staff and ss.id_shop = 2) ) 
ELSE 
(SELECT (to_date(to_char(ss.change_date, 'yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM') <= to_date('2019-02-16', 'yyyy-MM')) 
 FROM shop_staff_relationvm ss WHERE ss.id_staff = s.id_staff and ss.id_shop = 2 ) 
END);
```

The part of query I have problem with :

```
((SELECT ((LEAD (to_date(to_char(ss.change_date, 'yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM')) OVER (ORDER BY ss.id_staff DESC)) > to_date('2019-02-16', 'yyyy-MM') ) 
FROM shop_staff_relationvm ss WHERE ss.id_staff = s.id_staff and ss.id_shop !=2 LIMIT 1)
and 
(SELECT (MIN(to_date(to_char(ss.change_date, 'yyyy-MM'), 'yyyy-MM')) <= to_date('2019-02-16', 'yyyy-MM'))
FROM shop_staff_relationvm ss WHERE ss.id_staff = s.id_staff and ss.id_shop = 2))
```

Comment: Your question is about one table, but your code includes other tables.

Comment: yes because I need some data from staff table too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the staff on a particular date, you can use `distinct on`.

```
select distinct on (ss.id_staff) ss.*
from shop_staff_relationvm ss 
where ss.change_date <= '2019-02-01'::date
order by ss.id_staff, ss.change_date desc;
```

With an index on `shop_staff_relationvm(id_staff, change_date)`, this is probably the best performing of possible solutions.

To determine who is at a particular shop, use a subquery:

```
select s.*
from (select distinct on (ss.id_staff) ss.*
      from shop_staff_relationvm ss 
      where ss.change_date <= '2019-02-01'::date
      order by ss.id_staff, ss.change_date desc
     ) s
where s.shop_id = 2;
```